# WebpackDevServer Proxy Setup

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server

How do I set up a proxy using WebpackDevServer in my React/Node chrome extension? My server is run on `localhost:4000` and React frontend on `localhost:5000`

Using Axios, I try and hit the route: `axios.get(/api/user/ticket)`, however, `localhost:4000` is not proxied and the route that is hit is my chrome extension: `chrome-extension://fjkfhdsjkwerjhdksfhdjkshfds/api/ticket/user/`.

If I explicitly call localhost: `axios.get(localhost:4000/api/user/ticket)`, then everything works properly. I'm new to webpack so not fully sure what I'm doing wrong. Thank you for the help!

**Webserver proxy implemented using the [docs](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserverproxy)**

```
var server = new WebpackDevServer(
  {
    https: false,
    hot: false,
    client: false,
    proxy: {
      '/api': 'http://localhost:4000',
    },
    host: 'localhost',
    port: env.PORT,
    static: {
      directory: path.join(__dirname, '../build'),
    },
    devMiddleware: {
      publicPath: `http://localhost:${env.PORT}/`,
      writeToDisk: true,
    },
    headers: {
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
    },
    //this needs to change to prevent dns attacks
    allowedHosts: 'all',
  },
  compiler
);
```

Comment: How about using the proxy option in `package.json`: `"proxy": "http://localhost:4000",` Does that work? [This is CRA documentation](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/proxying-api-requests-in-development/) but it should still work.

Comment: I added ` "proxy": "http://localhost:4000"` to package.json and it unfortunately does not work either. I've also implemented both solutions at the same time and that doesn't work as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Proxy still doesn't work, however, I got around this by using baseUrls in axios. When in prod vs dev I just have to change them in one place and it works. Not ideal but it gets the job done.